# HTML / Javascript: multiple onClick functions firing order / delays?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

a basic understanding question:

Have an element with onClick action - multiple javascript calls being made:

```
onclick="function1();function2();function3()"
```

However, as function 3 is depending on the function1 action, I need to make sure the function3 is not firing untill function1 is all done. And that does not seem to be the natural order of things, in practice it seems that all 3 functions are firing more or less at the same time (at least not waiting for eachother to finish). Anyway I can achieve this?

EDIT: can't do it all from same functinon call, it is (mostly) ajax calls that updates certain div's...

FURTHER EDIT: Okay, can see that maybe it needs even further clarification (thought there was a simple, logical way to handle it, build in so to speak)...

The function calls are firing ajax action, which hare - thru PHP - updating content on the page (div's). If I should use a return value, then I should modify my central ajax js function so that it will return something on completion and only fire the next function if this value has been set? Anyone has a good snippet to do this in one single onClick event..? :-)

OR ... as something af a hack - should I just stick a 1 second delay in front of function3? :-) How would I go about that directly inside the onClick event..? :-)

Comment: why don't you aggregate all functions in one?

Comment: With that code, each function will be called in turn. No function will  be called before the previous one is finished. It is possible that a function will do something later (e.g. if it calls `setTimeout` or sets up an event handler, but there is no generic way to trap that. You have to write a callback specific to the thing that is making it run the code later).

Comment: Maybe I should specify (thanks to all who has already answered) - function1 makes some updates to the db and updates a div (ajax) ... function3 (all is ofcourse just seudo examples) updates another div, and this is dependent on the db action from function1. In live examples I can see that function3 updates the div BEFORE function1 has made its update...

Comment: Is your database replicated or under heavy load?

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at my answer below. Modification: call your `function2();` in your ajax call. If you use jQuery, use the `success` property/event and place that call in there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you do not want to change the onclick definition, then you can do it like this:

```
onclick="function1();function2();function3();"
```

Script:

```
function1Complete = false;

function1(){
// some stuff
function1Complete = true;
}

function3(){
  if (function1Complete){
    // Put your code here
  }else{
    setTimeout(function3, 1000);
  }
}
```

This is not the best and Clean solution. But this will help you, if you do not have any other solution.

Comment: well, wouldn't that just ensure that the content of function3 is never run, more or less...? :-))

Comment: @BrianLanghoff Not so long as function 1 completes and sets the flag properly. It ensures that function 3 can't run unless function 1 is finished, which seems to be the behaviour you're after.

Comment: Thanks, ended up implementing something like your suggestion in my javascript ajax routine - and does the trick :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can work with callbacks:

```
function function1(callback) {
    // do your stuff
    if (callback) { callback(); } // calls your next function
}
function function2(callback) {
    // do your stuff
    if (callback) { callback(); } // calls your next function
}
function function3() {
    // function 3 stuff
}
```

if you depend on a `setTimeout` to finish, simply add your call to the callback in your `setTimeout` part.

and call it like this:

```
<a onclick="function1(function() { function2( function() { function3() }) });">call functions</a>
```

Comment: This would call function 3, then call function 2, then call whatever function 3 returned, then call function 1, then call whatever function 2 returned.

Comment: Callbacks, if properly implemented, might be *part* of a solution to the problem. But at the moment there isn't enough code in the question to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Hideously ugly, and rather speculative as to what the problem is.

Comment: I agree, but he asked for a solution to the problem "how can I fire 3 functions sequentially via the onclick event of a HTML element" and this is a possible solution for it that works. If the question were more specific we could provide a nice solution.

Comment: The code in the question itself is *also* a possible solution for it that works. :) It wasn't (it's been edited to be clearer) specific enough to determine what the problem actually is, which is why I made a comment instead of trying to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

instead for calling all there functions directly onClick you should try calling one function from another

something like this:

```
onClick="function1()"
```

and then from funtion1() call funtion2()

```
function function1()
{
//your code here

funtion2();

}
```

and so on....

Comment: Just sticking the function call at the end of the previous function won't make any difference. If `function1` called `setTimeout` (for example) then putting a call to `function2` at the end of the function *called by* `setTimeout` would, but we don't know if `setTimeout` is being used or if something else is being used or if the OP is just misinterpreting the results he is getting.

Comment: For my solution I was like DUH I need function2 to run after function1 anyway..but then I was like oh..I have something else that calls function1 that *doesnt* run function2..so the problem is, that specific onClick might be only place one needs those specific functions to run.

Comment: However, I just sent an extra parameter through the onclick that I *did* want to run function2. If this parameter was `true` (had value) then run function2, otherwise function1 ends. This did the trick for me! The callback stuff in Zim84's answer looks too messy and I didn't like the idea of a `timeout`.